# i can't fix this segmentation fault

Tags: arrays, c, file, bitmap, segmentation-fault

This code should read a bitmap of undefined length for both rows and columns, such as this

```
25 6

1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

The first number (25) is the total number of pixel in the image, the second number (6) is the number of shades of grey

Save it into a pointer f through the function "load image" and then analyze it with other function.

For example it should return  the frequence of each grey shade.

The data elaboration works fine, but the function borders gives me segmentation fault.

It should switch each value on the borders of the pixel map with the value "val" I give to the function. in this case it's zero

How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>


void read_dim_grey(FILE *fin, int *p, int *g)
{
    fscanf(fin, "%d %d", p, g);
}

int **img_alloc(int n_row, int n_col)
{
    int **p;
    int i; 
    if ((p = malloc(n_row * sizeof(*p)))  ==  NULL) {
        printf("not enough memory !\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n_row; i++) {
        p[i] = malloc(n_col * sizeof(*p));
        if (p[i] == NULL) {
            printf("not enough memory\n");
        exit(-1);
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int *vect_alloc(int n)
{
    int *p;
    p = malloc(n * sizeof(*p));
    if (p  ==  NULL) {
        printf("not enough memory !\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
        
    return p;
}

void load_img(int **img_in, int n_row, int n_col, FILE *fin)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n_row; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < n_col; j++) {
            fscanf(fin, "%d", img_in[i] + j);
        }
    
}

void calculate_freq(int **img, int n_row, int n_col, int *f)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n_row; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < n_col; j++) 
            f[img[i][j]]++;
}

void frequence(int *freq, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", freq[i]);
    }
}


void filter(int *freq, int n, int val)
{
    int i, tot = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (freq[i] == val) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            tot++;
        }
    }
    if (tot == 0)
        printf("NESSUNO\n");
}

void missing(int *freq, int n)
{
    filter(freq, n,  0);
}

void prevalent(int *freq, int n)
{
    int i, max = freq[0];
        for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if(freq[i] > max)
                max = freq[i];
        }
        filter(freq, n, max);
}

double average( int **img,  int n_row, int n_col)
{
    int i, j;
    double somma = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n_row; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < n_col; j++)
            somma += img[i][j];
    return somma/(n_row*n_col);
}


void tozero(int *f, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        f[i] = 0;
}
void borders(int **img, int n_row, int n_col, int val)
{
    int i, j;
    for(j = 0; i < n_col; j++) 
        img[0][j] = val;
    for(j = 0; i < n_col; j++) 
        img[n_row - 1][j] = val;
    for(i = 1; i < n_row ; i++)  {
        img[i][0] = val;
        img[i][n_col - 1] = val;
    }
}
int main(int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fin;
    int n_row, n_col, n_pixel,  n_grey, prof;
    int **img_in, *freq;
    
    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("e niente, non sono abbaastanza gli aargomenti, mannaggia");
        }
    
    if (!(fin = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        printf("uso: %s <img_input> \n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    read_dim_grey(fin, &n_pixel, &prof);
    n_grey = (int)pow(2, prof);
    n_row = n_col = sqrt(n_pixel);
    img_in = img_alloc(n_row, n_col);
    load_img(img_in, n_row, n_col, fin);
    freq = vect_alloc(n_grey);
    calculate_freq(img_in, n_row, n_col, freq);

    
    printf("[FREQUENZE]\n");
    frequence(freq, prof);

    printf("[MANCANTI]\n");
    missing(freq, prof);

    printf("[PREVALENTI]\n");
    prevalent(freq, prof);
        
    printf("[MEDIA]\n");
    printf("%.2lf\n", average(img_in, n_row, n_col));

    borders(img_in, n_row, n_col, 0);

    //tozero(freq, n_grey);
    //calculate_freq(img_in,  n_row, n_col, freq);
    //printf("FREQUENZE AGGIORNATE\n");
    //frequence(freq, n_grey);

    //printf("[MEDIA AGGIORNATA]\n");
    //printf("%.2lf \n", average(img_in, n_row, n_col));
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `imc_alloc()`, `p[i] = malloc(n_col * sizeof(*p));` is wrong. It should be `sizeof(**p)` (== `sizeof(int)` instead. But it's unlikely that this causes the problem, because normally `sizeof(int *) >= sizeof(int)`

Comment: Check is none of your array indexes goes out of bounds and/or use your debugger. You need to add some code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a segfault because your variable p is `int **`and you want to init `p`like this.

```c
p = malloc(n_row * sizeof(*p);
```

Or as I said before your p variable is ``int **```so for fix your bug you should write this down :

```c
p = malloc(n_row * sizeof(**p);
```

Definition to sizeof:

Sizeof is a much used operator in the C or C++. It is a compile time unary operator which can be used to compute the size of its operand. The result of sizeof is of unsigned integral type which is usually denoted by size_t. sizeof can be applied to any data-type, including primitive types such as integer and floating-point types, pointer types, or compound datatypes such as Structure, union etc.

link to better understand: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member/